# c# string with button name change back color

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get a string with the name of the button that I will change the color on.
but how do I find button and get accesses to the color change.

I build a web page in c #

hope someone can help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB6FC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Page.FindControl("yourControlName") to change its properties.

```
Button myButton = (Button) Page.FindControl("yourButtonName");
myButton.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue
```

Comment: i only get the last of the name I added a picture

Comment: Okay it works with another button name party PARTY :-) I just change 300 button names then it works 8-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..its a C# WFA code..hope it works

```
foreach (Button button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
                //button.Enabled = false;
                if (button.Name == "button2")
                    button.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Comment: If ( button.Name== "button2") .Name does not work :-(

Comment: seems silly to ask ..but did you change button2 to your button name??